# flutter Unhandled this in defaultTreeNode

Tags: flutter

what does the error in title actually mean? as I come up with it really often, and usually itjust disappears with few manipulations with code, which aren't something exact.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xo_xo_xo/data/matrix.dart';
```

it must be problem with my widget state

```
class _GameFieldWidgetState extends State<GameFieldWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: widget.field.rows.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
          var rowIndex = entry.key;
          var rowValue = entry.value;
          var border = new Border(
              top: rowIndex == 0
                  ? BorderSide.none
                  : new BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              bottom: rowIndex == 2
                  ? BorderSide.none
                  : new BorderSide(color: Colors.black));
          return Expanded(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: border),
              child: Row(
                children: rowValue.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                  var columnIndex = entry.key;
                  var columnValue = entry.value;
                  var onCellPressed = () {
                    widget.onCellPressed(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                  };

                  var border = new Border(
                      left: columnIndex == 0
                          ? BorderSide.none
                          : new BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      right: columnIndex == 2
                          ? BorderSide.none
                          : new BorderSide(color: Colors.black));
                  return Expanded(
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: border),
                      child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: onCellPressed,
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(columnValue,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontSize: 48.0)))),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

In this case I jut can't get rid of it.

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] so you can find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and was fortunate to find a solution. Your code looks ok and probably is (if the IDE shows no errors, it's probably not your code). 
This is an unfortunate bug in Dart's implementation of implicit `new` and `const`, tracked here: [github issue #32737](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32737)

For reference, here is the related [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16242).

What worked for me: I added explicit `new`. For example

```
      return Expanded(
        child: DecoratedBox(
```

becomes

```
      return new Expanded(
        child: new DecoratedBox(
```

in your code.

Comment: Got it figured out by myself few days ago, though forgotten to add it here, anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow I wasted a solid couple hours trying to sort this out with no resolve. Thank you!!!